# In an MVC pattern, what's the best way to avoid calls to the controller in my view class?

Tags: javascript, optimization, model-view-controller

I've been using RaphaelJS to draw shapes on a canvas. After drawing, I need to add an event listener to each shape. The easiest way to do that is to use something like this:

```
    sym.click((e)=>{
        this._controller.responseFunction(e);
    });
```

It's not terrible, but it does mean that my view will always need knowledge of my controller. Is there a better way to add event listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea in your scenario with publish subscribe pattern:

```
sym.click((e) => {
   pubSub.fireEvent('sym.click', ...yourArguments)
});
```

Then in your controller you would listen with:

```
pubSub.subscribe('sym.click', myhandlerFunction)
```

Where `myhandlerFunction` is a function handling the event with the provided arguments.

This way your view would not need to have an actual reference to your controller and it would be more de-coupled. The only reference needed in this scenario is to the pub-sub mechanism.

You could implement that mechanism yourself (plenty of examples online) or use a library such as [pubsubjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js), [publish-subscribe-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/publish-subscribe-js) etc.